# Как совместить 2 блока в 1

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 блока с одинаковыми названиями, как сделать так, чтобы они объединились в 1 и все содержимое второго и первого блока были в одном, пример, есть такой код:

```html
            <div class="payment">
                <div class="q">
                    <p>some information</p>
                </div>   
            </div>

            <div class="payment">
                <div class="w">
                    <p>some information2.0</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

и мне нужно чтобы с помощью например javascript он объединился в 1 блок с классом payment

```html
<!-- так должно быть после махинаций с js -->

<div class="payment">
                <div class="q">
                    <p>some information</p>
                </div>   
            
                <div class="w">
                    <p>some information2.0</p>
                </div>  
</div>
```

Заранее большое спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим так

```js
function MergeElements(selector, from) { // selector - селектор элементов которые нужно объединить, from - индекс элемента, в который будем объединять 
    selector = document.querySelectorAll(selector); // найдём все эти элементы
    let $from = selector[from]; // отдельно сохраним элемент в который будем объединять
    [...selector].map((e, i) => { // Пройдёмся циклом по всем элементам
        if(i !== from) { // Если индекс элемента !== индексу from, то выполняем следующее:
            [...e.childNodes].map(e => $from.appendChild(e)); // Берём все дочерние элемены и добавляем их в элемент который объединяем
            e.remove(); // удаляем ненужный selector
        }
    });
}

MergeElements('.payment', 0);
```

```html
<div class="payment">
    <div class="q">
        <p>some information</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="payment">
    <div class="w">
        <p>some information2.0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Чутка защиты..

```js
function MergeElements(selector, from = 0) {
    selector = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    if(selector.length >= 2
  && from >= 0
  && from < selector.length) {
        let $from = selector[from];
        [...selector].map((e, i) => {
            if (i !== from) {
                [...e.childNodes].map((e) => $from.appendChild(e));
                e.remove();
            }
        });
    }
}

MergeElements('.payment')
```

```html
<div class="payment" data-id="1">
    <div class="q">
        <p>some information</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="payment" data-id="2">
    <div class="w">
        <p>some information2.0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: M**e**rgeElements

Comment: @Igor, спасибо)